# glsl fractal shader for raylib not working correctly

Tags: glsl, fractals, newtons-method, raylib

https://github.com/bananaboy139/fractal/tree/OpenGL-shader

https://github.com/bananaboy139/fractal/blob/OpenGL-shader/images/2.png?raw=true
this is the original image I made with zig.

[https://github.com/bananaboy139/fractal/blob/OpenGL-shader/images/I%20don't%20know%20what%20happened%20part%202.png?raw=true](https://github.com/bananaboy139/fractal/blob/OpenGL-shader/images/I%20don%27t%20know%20what%20happened%20part%202.png?raw=true)
this is the image I get from the shader.

(I can't post images, I don't have 10 reputation)

it's supposed to iterate over newton's optimization of z^{3} - 1
and use the pixel's coordinates as the complex number for z.

I moved from using zig to calculate it to using a shader because zig was far too slow to be able to use to explore the fractal. With the shader, it is much faster, only problem is that it's wrong. I assume that the problem is with my implementation of complex numbers, but I have no clue where.

Euler form is when it is expressed as radius * e^{i*theta}
Cartesian is the classic a + bi

here's the shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 fragTexCoord;
in vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec2 screenDims;
uniform float acceptable_err;
uniform int max_trial;
uniform vec2 offset;
uniform float zoom;

out vec4 color;


const float PI = 3.1415926535;

struct Complex_cartesian {
    float re;
    float im;
};

struct Complex_euler {
    float radius;
    float theta;
};

//cartesian to euler
Complex_euler C_c__to__C_e(Complex_cartesian z) {
    float r = sqrt(pow(z.re, 2) + pow(z.im, 2));
    float t = atan(z.im/z.re);
    return(Complex_euler(r, t));
}
//euler to cartesian
Complex_cartesian C_e__to__C_c(Complex_euler z) {
    float a = z.radius * cos(z.theta);
    float b = z.radius * sin(z.theta);
    return(Complex_cartesian(a, b));
}
//complex addition
Complex_cartesian C_add(Complex_cartesian z_1, Complex_cartesian z_2) {
    return(Complex_cartesian(z_1.re + z_2.re, z_1.im + z_2.im));
}
//complex subtraction
Complex_cartesian C_sub(Complex_cartesian z_1, Complex_cartesian z_2) {
    return(Complex_cartesian(z_1.re - z_2.re, z_1.im - z_2.im));
}
//complex division
Complex_euler C_div(Complex_euler z_1, Complex_euler z_2) {
    return(Complex_euler(z_1.radius / z_2.radius, z_1.theta - z_2.theta));
}
//complex multiplication
Complex_euler C_mul(Complex_euler z_1, Complex_euler z_2) {
    return(Complex_euler(z_1.radius * z_2.radius, z_1.theta + z_2.theta));
}
//complex powers
Complex_euler C_pow(Complex_euler z, float power) {
    return(Complex_euler(pow(z.radius, power), z.theta * power));
}

//absolute answers
const Complex_euler z_1 = Complex_euler(1, 0);
const Complex_euler z_2 = Complex_euler(1, 2.0*PI/3.0);
const Complex_euler z_3 = Complex_euler(1, 4.0*PI/3.0);
const Complex_euler answers[3] = Complex_euler[3](z_1, z_2, z_3);

float check_err(Complex_cartesian guess, Complex_euler ans) {
    Complex_cartesian Cart_ans = C_e__to__C_c(ans);
    return(C_div(C_c__to__C_e(C_sub(Cart_ans, guess)), ans).radius);
}

float check(Complex_cartesian guess) {
    float errs[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        errs[i] = check_err(guess, answers[i]);
    }
    //really cool sort 2.0
    if (errs[1] > errs[2]) {
        errs[1] = errs[2];
    }
    if (errs[0] > errs[1]) {
        errs [0] = errs[1];
    }
    return(errs[0]);
}

Complex_euler optimized(Complex_euler z) {
    //2z^3+1 / 3*z^2
    Complex_cartesian top = C_add(C_e__to__C_c(C_mul(Complex_euler(2, 0), C_pow(z, 3))), Complex_cartesian(1, 0));
    Complex_euler bottom = C_mul(Complex_euler(3, 0), C_pow(z, 2));
    return(C_div(C_c__to__C_e(top), bottom));
}

void main() {
    Complex_cartesian coor = Complex_cartesian((fragTexCoord.x + offset.x/screenDims.x)/zoom, (fragTexCoord.y + offset.y/screenDims.y)/zoom);
    Complex_euler z = C_c__to__C_e(coor);
    float trial = 0.0;
    while ((check(C_e__to__C_c(z)) > acceptable_err) && (trial < max_trial)) {
        z = optimized(z);
        trial += 1;
    }
    trial /= 500;
    // trial *= 10;
    color = vec4(trial, trial, trial, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/fldBWN

I think the main issue is with `atan` function. To get a full-360 angle from a direction one typically goes with `atan(y, x)` (aka "atan2" in other programming languages), while the inverse tangent of `x/y` is ambiguous.